# Meaning of Pudding of a young man

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Could someone explain what the pudding means here. I'm a bit confused.

> From the stammering and awkward conversation, she had with Haroun that
>   day Naveed  discovered to her consternation that her future husband
>   had no ambitions and a tiny appetite. Nor was he in any hurry to have
>   children. The confidence with which Naveed had stated, 'I'll fix him,'
>   ebbed out of her in the physical presence of this **pudding of a young
>   man**
>
> *From Salman Rushdie - Shame.*

From wider context: Naveed met her future husband Haroun for the first time and is really disappointed.

Comment: A "pig of a man" is someone who looks like or behaves like a pig.  A "pudding of a man" is someone who looks like a pudding, and has no spine or ambitions.  Also, there's nothing special about him.  He's bland.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by the Oxford dictionary, the term "pudding" means a dessert of creamy consistency but can also be used informally as an insulting term for a person.  In its informal sense, it carries connotations that the person is fat and stupid.  See https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/pudding for the full explanation.

The insult - especially for a man - comes from the fact that a pudding is, by definition, **very soft** and typically **shapeless** (or taking the shape of the bowl in which it is served rather than having a strong shape of its own).

Naveed is clearly looking for a "manly" man who has ambitions, a strong appetite and a wish to start a family.

By using the term "pudding of a man" to refer to Haroun, the author shows that Naveed considers Haroun as weak, soft and shapeless.

Comment: _Pudding_ is a creamy dessert in American English, but Rushdie is British-educated and was resident in the UK when he wrote _Shame_. I suspect he was thinking of the traditional solid pudding of dough or cake mixture boiled or steamed in a basin. like some of [these](https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/collections/old_fashioned_puddings) (though Haroun presumably isn't fat if he has a small appetite).

Comment: @KateBunting - That's a great point, Kate!  It explains the difference between the way in which I would normally use the term (as the British do) and the defined meaning from Lexico.  I referred to the latter, because this site often penalises contributors who don't use references (which is a practice I don't agree with, because dictionaries very often miss common usage).  Since the Lexico definition was good enough, I used it anyway.

Comment: @KateBunting - BTW, I'd be happy for you to edit my answer, if you feel you can improve on it with your additional info and link.

Comment: Your link is to the 'US dictionary' section of Lexico. If you select 'Dictionary' from the drop-down menu you get ' _British_ A cooked sweet dish served after the main course of a meal.'